# ast-compare package of nodejs returns false if ast contains null value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using ast-compare package to compare 2 ast.
my ast constains null value init. ast-compare returns false even if 2 ast are same.
if I change null to "null", it returns true.
here is my code :

```
const compare = require("ast-compare");
var result = compare({
            "type": "FunctionExpression",
            "id": null,
            "params": [
              {
                "type": "Identifier",
                "name": "",
                "value": ""
              }
            ],
            "generator": false,
            "expression": false,
            "async": false
          },{
            "type": "FunctionExpression",
            "id": null,
            "params": [
                {
                "type": "Identifier",
                "name": "",
                "value": ""
                }
            ],
            "generator": false,
            "expression": false,
            "async": false
            })

console.log(result) // it returns false
```

If I change null to "null" in both ast, then it returns true.